# Is it possible to add a custom directive in ag-grid in angular 6?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am new to angular .. how do I add our custom directive in ag-grid using angular 6. I didn't find any information about adding directive in ag-grid. By using cellrenderFrameWork, we can add component but not directive... I don't know how to add. In my application i want to add Highlightin ag-grid cell using custom directive... please help me about this one.

Here is My directive [Highlight].

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[Highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    //  alert('direactive' + initalValue);
    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if (initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to initializ directive in normal component like

component.html :

```
<input type="text" Highlight>
```

Now i have to add my [Highlight] directive in aggrid cell. please send any example of aggrid with directive

Answer (score -1):

You want to use custom directive for your number validation in your [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid). Which means that,...

- You are doing inline edit. Which implies that
- You need to use `cellEditor`. Since you need apply your custom validations
- You need to use `cellEditorFramework`. As you have the validation directive,
- You can use this directive in the editor template for validation.

For more details on how to have custom editor, have a look at [Dynamic Editor Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-dynamic-editor-component) and check the `moodEditor`

Comment: They didn't use directive anywhere in that code....i don't want to write code again and agian. i created directive like shared one, so can i use that shared directive in aggrid?

Comment: Not able to get what you are asking. See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: sorry for my mistake and thanks for your reply. actually i created one directive in shared module, so it  should be work  in all components in all modules. My question is i want use directive in aggrid cell, by using cell editor we can set our own validation but how to add directive instead of writing code in cell editor.... please help me

Comment: You need to write the code the way `ag-grid` is expecting. If you want to use your directive for validation, check the steps I've provided

Comment: now check the above question , you can understand my problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... it is very clear, Can we add a directive to a cell without having to use a cellRenderer or cellEditor?